# Request to retrieve by an API the profile URL (vanity name)

Tags: linkedin-api

We're applaime - developing an AI driven product which will help job seekers to manage more effectively the job application process.
The product will enable Linkedin oauth authentication after which it is expected to retieve the current user's basic profile.
Hence we would like to apply for this permission (r_basicprofile). How can we get this process in motion?

Thanks.

Trying to fetch the basic profile via an API. Need permission for that.

Answer (score 0):

This page describes how to get access to the various APIs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/getting-access.